# Как отправить Multipart-запрос через SoapUI?

Tags: java, ubuntu, soapui, multipart

Всем привет.

Тестирую REST-запросы через SoapUI. Нужно отправить картинку как MultipartFile. Есть ли какой-то русскоязычный гайд или дельный совет, как это сделать?

Как вообще создаются Multipart-запросы через SoapUI? Пытался вставить ссылку на файл, но не работает. У меня Ubuntu 16.04.

Спасибо.

Comment: Кто-то еще использует этот ужасный SOAP?

Comment: Бармалей, Вы регулярно пишете комментарии к моим постам и ни разу по теме. Спасибо за Ваш комментарий, больше не надо.

Comment: Это правда, видимо, такие вопросы - ничего личного

Comment: какая версия SoapUI?

Comment: @Barmaley вы видимо не особо в вопросе разобрались. SoapUI работает со всеми видами http запросов, а не только с soap.

Comment: @Barmaley я нисколько не обижусь, если Вы не будете больше спамить в комментариях к моим вопросам. На каждый мой вопрос находится квалифицированный ответ, думаю, Вам не стоит больше тратить своё время. Ничего личного.

Comment: @Okdel версия 5.3.0

Comment: в версиях 5.х в нижней части экрана с запросом должна быть кнопка attachment. она открывает менюшку по добавлению файлов в запрос. а тип запроса можно указать в поле mediatype, там будет выпадающий список в котором можно выбрать multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, пересел с SoapUI на Postman — всё намного проще и понятнее.